# Disabling the Links on the Picture Library Slideshow webpart. or ammending the code to open the link in the same window

Tags: 2010, javascript, picture-library

I am using SharePoint 2010 Picture library Slideshow webpart. But want to disable the link from opening in another window.

I have used the following code succesfully to change the image link to the page link.
[<WebPartPages:PictureLibrarySlideshowWebPart adding links](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/13503/webpartpagespicturelibraryslideshowwebpart-adding-links/92345#92345)

in particular this line of code.

ssObj.link.href = '';  //<--put your custom picture link url here

I have a customer requirement to disable links from the slideshow. Is there a way of getting the javascript code in the link above to just go back to the top of the page in the same page? Maybe using the #top or _self ? giving the illusion of the link being redundant.