# adding links to PictureLibrarySlideshowWebPart and opening it on the same tab/page

Tags: javascript, web-part, picture-library

I'm using the code on page, [<WebPartPages:PictureLibrarySlideshowWebPart adding links](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/13503/webpartpagespicturelibraryslideshowwebpart-adding-links/203473), for adding the link to the slideshow pic webpart but I'd like to open the link in the same tab/window.  Is it possible?  If so, please suggest the lines of codes to make this happen.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function SlideshowObjectInitializer() {
  ShowPic = (function(ShowPicOrig) {
      return function() {
           var ssObj = arguments[0];  //SlideShow object
           var curPicIdx=ssObj.index; //current picture index
           ShowPicOrig.apply(this, arguments); //call original ShowPic
           ssObj.link.href = '';  //<--put your custom picture link url here 
      };
  })(ShowPic);
}  
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(SlideshowObjectInitializer, 'imglib.js');
</script>
```

Comment: What is the value of ssObj? Is ssObj an anchor tag?